# Match any comma and dot in currency format, but not the last one

Tags: php, regex, currency

I want to convert money format to decimal, which is will be stored in the database as decimal data type

example:

```
12,345.45 to 12345.45
10.000.00 to 10000.00
```

I've tried with this regex pattern `/(,|\.)/` but the last dot(indicate cents value) still involved, I was confused about how to exclude the last dot

#### expected result, exclude the last dot in given string

Comment: Better approach - don't try to parse the display value into an internal value. Keep two entirely separate values - one is the internal representation, the other the display value. If you need to *do* anything with the money (add, subtract, save to DB, etc), then use the internal value. If you need to *show* the money, use the display format. A reasonable alternative is to do the exact opposite of what you do here - only keep the internal format but pass it through some function to convert it to display format. Then never read back that display format.

Comment: @VLAZ the problem is, from the user input formatted like that(for human readable), and I want to store the user input to the database as a decimal value

Comment: So, what happens if they put in, say `1.000` meaning `1000`? Is that going to be turned into just `1`?

Comment: no, I used javascript for format the number, e.g user input is ``12546`` then I format the input, so will look like this ``12,546.00``, that if the user not including the cent on the behind, if user input the cent e.g ``12546.54`` so it will be ``12,546.54``, that what wil be displayed after user input before stored to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `php`, you may use `preg_replace` like this:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/\.(?=\d+\.)|,/', '', $str);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2hMSmD/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\.`: Match `.`
- `(?=\d+\.)`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have a dot ahead after 1+ digits
- `|`: OR
- `,`: Match a comma

Comment: Cool, this work and great explanation, thanks